# Continuity, algebraic and rational numbers

Tags: continuity

Is it true that there exist a continuous function f that for every algebraic number q , his image f(q) is a rational number?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: The constant function $f(x)=42$?

Comment: There even exists a strictly increasing such function. See the first bullet [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method).

Answer (score 2):

Yes -- there is even a *strictly increasing* continuous bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that the image of the algebraic reals is exactly the rational numbers.

The key to this is that both the algebraic reals and the rational numbers are *countable dense total orders without first or last element*, and it is a [general theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method) that every such two sets are order-isomorphic. Since both sets are dense in $\mathbb R$, an isomorphism between them extends uniquely to a continuous function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

(Even better, *every* strictly increasing continuous bijection $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ can be uniformly approximated by such functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it with an entire function.

EDIT: Here's one way to construct an entire function that maps $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb A$ to $\mathbb Q[i]$, and is one-to-one on $\mathbb R$.
Here $\mathbb A$ is the algebraic numbers (not necessarily real) and $\mathbb Q$ the rationals.

Start by fixing an enumeration $a_k$ of $\{z \in \mathbb A: \text{Im}(z) \ge 0\}$.
The function will be of the form

$$ f(z) = z + \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(z)$$

where $f_j$ are chosen inductively so that, writing $F_j(z) = z + \sum_{k=1}^j f_k(z)$,

1. $f_j(\overline{z}) = \overline{f_j(z)}$.  In particular, $f_j$ maps $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$.
2. $f_k(a_j) = 0$ for $j < k$.  Thus $f(a_j) = F_j(a_j)$.
3. $F_j(a_j) \in \mathbb Q[i]$.
4. $|f_j(z)| \le 2^{-j}$ for $|z| < j$.  This will imply that the series converges uniformly on compact sets to an entire function.
5. $|f'_j(z)| \le 2^{-j-1}$ on $\mathbb R$.  This will imply that $f'(z) \ge 1/2$, so $f$ maps $\mathbb R$ one-to-one onto $\mathbb R$.

Given $f_k$ for $k < j$, we start with  $$ h(z) = e^{-z^2} \prod_{k < j} (z - a_k)(z - \overline{a_k})$$ which satisfies (1) and (2).

If $\alpha_j \in \mathbb R$, then $h(\alpha_j) \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$ and $F_{j-1}(\alpha_j) \in \mathbb R$.  Since $h$ is bounded on $\{z: |z| \le j\}$
and $h'$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that (4) and (5) are true
with $f_j (z) = t h(z)$ as long as $|t| < \epsilon$, and (3) will be true for a dense set of $t \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

If $\alpha_j \notin \mathbb R$, (3) is a bit more complicated.  We therefore
take $f_j(z) = (t + s z) h(z)$: there will still be $\epsilon > 0$ such that (4) and (5) hold for  $(s,t) \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)^2$, and for a dense set of such $(s,t)$ we will have (3).

Comment: Hmm, I see. Can you also achieve both $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb R$ and $f(\mathbb A)=\mathbb Q[i]$ with a bijective entire function?

Comment: Bijective on $\mathbb R$, I hope you mean.  There aren't too many entire functions bijective on $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'd guess this is an instance of a more general theorem, could you state it?

Comment: @Robert: Hmm, right. So the best we can do for the complex algebraics is probably an entire function $f$ such that $f^{-1}(\mathbb Q[i])\supsetneq \mathbb A$.

Comment: I think we can still have $f^{-1}(\mathbb Q[i]) = \mathbb A$ by modifying the construction, ensuring at stage $j$ that any $w$ with $|w| \le j$ for which $F_j(w)$  is of the first $j$ members of $\mathbb Q[i]$ (in a fixed enumeration) is in $\mathbb A$, and making $f_k(w) = 0$ for $k > j$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Hmm, I'm not convinced. If we look at some transcendental $w$, I'll buy that your modification can ensure that $F_j(w)$ eventually avoids every member of $\mathbb Q[i]$. But that won't necessarily prevent $\lim_{j\to\infty} F_j(w)$ from being in $\mathbb Q[i]$ anyway. You can't require $f_k(w)=0$ for _every_ $w$ that is in danger of converging towards $\mathbb Q[i]$ because that's all of them, uncountably many!

Comment: If $f(w) = z \in \mathbb Q[i]$ with multiplicity $m$, take $r > 0$ such that $w$ is the only zero of $f - z$ within distance $r$ of $w$.  By Rouché's theorem there exists  $N$ such that for $n > N$,  $F_n - z$ has exactly $m$ zeros (counted by multiplicity) within distance $r$ of $w$. 
But by construction, such zeros (if $n$ is large enough) are in $\mathbb A$ and will also be zeros of $F_k - z$ for all $k > n$, and therefore of $f - z$: thus they must be $w$, and $w \in \mathbb A$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Still not convinced. What prevents the $m$ zeroes of $F_n-z$ from being $a_j$s with $j>n$, and to keep moving to even later-in-the-enumeration $a_j$s as $n$ grows? A sequence of such $a_j$s would be able to converge to a transcendental $w$.

Comment: Further, it seems that the construction can easily be amended to make sure that all of the $F(a_j)$s are different, without losing anything you depend on. But $f$ is entire, definitely not affine, so it cannot be injective. Thus there will be $z_1\ne z_2$ with $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$. But then there is a neighborhood of $f(z_1)$ that is the continuous image of _disjoint_ neighborhoods of $z_1$ and $z_2$, such that a rational point in this neighborhood will be the image of both a point near $z_1$ and a different point near $z_2$. By construction these won't both be algebraic.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I had in mind, but it'll be better to edit the answer rather than trying to clarify with further comments.  I don't have time right now, but maybe later tonight...

Comment: Well, it does get complicated trying to write out the details.  But I'm quite confident the result is true.  In the amended construction, the value at $a_j$ may be assigned before stage $j$, in which case it won't be reassigned.  These values **cannot** be all different.  For a particular $w \in \mathbb Q[i]$ and $R > 0$, the roots of $F_j(z) - w$ with $|z| < R$ will be fixed at some stage, and they can't move after that.